# Разбить строку методом split() на массив который включает в себя разделитель

Tags: java, массивы, строки, split

Как разбить строку на массив методом split(), да так, чтобы сам разделитель тоже попал в массив? Код для примера:

```
public String[] splitUp(){
        String expression = "15+25";
        String[] strArr;
        strArr = expression.split("\\+");
                return strArr;
    }
```

Мне нужно разбить строку `expression` на массив, отделить числа друг от друга и чтобы сам плюсик не терялся, а тоже был элементом массива. Т.е. когда я пишу

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sp.splitUp("\\+"));
```

я получаю  `[15, 25]`, а мне нужно [15, +, 25]. Можно ли как-то это реализовать?

Comment: `.split( /([+])/ );` (в каких-то древних браузерах может глючить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно это решить с помощью регулярного выражения

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)|(\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("15+25*10/2");

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кроме плюса другие арифметические знаки (+,-,/,*), используйте регулярку
 `(?=[+\-*\/])|(?<=[+\-*\/])`